# Is it possible to set a separator for Zend Framework 2 form rows or display them in paragraphs?

Tags: php, zend-framework, formcollection

I have this for a form

```
$this->add(array(
        'name'=>'username',
        'type'=>'Text',
        'options'=>array(
            'label' => 'Username',
        )
    ));
$this->add(array(
        'name'=>'password',
        'type'=>'Password',
        'options'=>array(
            'label' => 'Password',
        )
    ));
```

and

```
echo $this->formCollection($form);
```

This are obviously just the relevant parts of the code. The output is as follows:

```
<fieldset ><label><span>Username</span><input type="text" name="username" value=""></label><label><span>Password</span><input type="password" name="password" value=""></label>
```

Is there any way to either put each row into a paragraph or to separate all the rows with line breaks? I read something about Decorators, but I'm not sure that was Zend Framework Version 2 and I don't know how to apply this to formCollection, if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is override the `formRow` helper with your own version that outputs the markup you want. I wrote a little [lib](https://packagist.org/packages/tfountain/tf-form) that does just this, feel free to use it or copy the approach.

Define your own helper: https://github.com/tfountain/tf-form/blob/master/src/TfForm/Form/View/Helper/FormRow.php and then update your module config to use it: https://github.com/tfountain/tf-form/blob/master/config/module.config.php

Comment: Cloned it into my project and works great, thank you. Only had to make a small change to the render function and add the $labelPosition parameter, else I got a fatal error due to compatibility.